# transition trigger event at the end

Tags: iphone

I use code below to add animation

```
animation.startProgress=fromPosition;
animation.endProgress=toPosition ;
```

Is it possible to get the event when animation reaches toPosition?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of considering [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)?

```
animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
```

And adding the completion handler block.